# empty array when set to null inside a functions still remains the same javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I was watching Douglas Crockford talk on javascript and he posted this question to solve.

```
function funky(o) {
  o = null;
}

var x = [];

funky(x);
console.log(x); //output []
```

To my surprise x is still [] and not null. Why is that?

Comment: what is your expectation ?

Comment: @brk am expecting **x** to be **null**